# Function to Place Commas Between Specific Characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that is not comma delimited that I would like to make comma delimited.  Fortunately, I know that every time the pair >< occurs I want to put a comma between them.  Is there a way to create such a function?  Thanks!

I did try this small macro as well, which merely deleted all the contents of the selected cell and replaced them with *>,<*.

```
Sub Replace()
  Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*><*", Replacement:=">,<", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

EDIT:  I have managed to get a comma between each instance of the string >< and now I am looking to figure out how to split up by row now so that after the phrase  a new row begins.

Comment: Looking at the macro, just remove the asterisks from the `What:="*><*"`.

Comment: @bendataclear Thanks, but I initially changed >,< to that because the same issue came up.  That said, I think the whole issue here might have been the fact that I was trying to do this in Excel.  Putting the information into Notepad allowed the regular find / replace function to work perfectly.  I will update my question with a follow-up in consideration of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat the CSV file as a text file not an Excel file.

Open it in a text editor like notepad (or Notepad++ <- my favourite) and perform a replace on `><` with `>,<`

Comment: I should mention, and this is likely outside the scope of the question, that I tried a sample of the cleaned up XML with </Result> at the end and all and found that it was not recognized when I attempted to import it to Access.  Would that suggest the file was corrupted somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Would this work? `Replace(inString, "><", ">,<")`

Comment: It would, but the formula is longer than 8192 characters, which seems to be the maximum for replace.  That said, this may not be the case when implementing Replace in VBA as you're suggesting.